# Removing unique i a index column

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I need to remove from a column the UNIQUE, mas is giving me a error

Thought in maybe if this is the reson droppig index and after dropping index add it again, but not sure if this is the right way.

This  is how i did in first migrate:
`$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unique()->index()->unsigned();`

Than this what I tried to do in dropping 
`$table->dropUnique(['user_id']);`

It gives e this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1553 Cannot drop index 'models_user_id_unique': needed in a foreign
>   key constraint (SQL: alter table `models` drop index
>   `models_user_id_unique`)

Comment: `needed in a foreign key constraint` - remove the FK first

Answer (score 0):

Drop the foreign key and Drop the unique index and Create the foreign key again

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('models', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(/* Foreign key name */);
    });

    Schema::table('models', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropUnique(['user_id']);
    });

    Schema::table('models', function (Blueprint $table) {
        /* Creating back the foreign key here */
    });
}
```